# How to edit MS Bot Framework Adaptive Card on submit action

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

In my bot i have an adaptive card with submit button. Can i modify card or disable button or delete this card on submit action ?

Comment: Would be good to share more details of your code and examples of the issue, but I believe I understand. You are saying that after the adaptive card is used (clicked on or whatever) you want it to go away so a user can't scroll back up and hit a button again? I don't know how to do that but I am interested in a solution as I can see how that could cause issues with your dialog flow.

Comment: Hi Andrii
Have you managed to do it? Because I only get 400 error when I try to execute UpdateActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teams you have the option of updating your card message. So you can use something like:

```
var newActivity = MessageFactory.Attachment(myUpdatedCard);
newActivity.Id = activityId //the Id of the original activity you sent;
await turnContext.UpdateActivityAsync(newActivity, cancellationToken);
```

To send a new version of the card.

Comment: WARNING!!! THIS CODE WORKING ONLY FOR TEAMS. NOT FOR EMULATOR. NOT FOR WEB CHAT. JUST TEAMS.

Comment: Yes, Teams is one of the bot channels that supports editing an existing message. Most channels do not.

Comment: I get a forbidden error while doing this , anyone  to help on this ?

Comment: You should only get a forbidden if the message was not created by the bot (the bot can only edit it's own messages)